# Why did an empty query-set appeared in my Django program?

Tags: python, django, django-views

```
def Cart(request):
    if request.user.is_authenticated:
         customer=request.user.customer
         order,created=Order.objects.get_or_create(customer=customer,complete=True)
         items=order.orderitem_set.all()
         print(items)
    else:
        items=[]

    context={"items":items}
    return render(request,'store/Cart.html',context)
```

i'm trying to show some orderitems in the Cart template but nothing appears so i tried to
print the items and  i get a an    despite in the admin pannel i assisgned in an order some orderitems

Answer (score 0):

try  this

```
def Cart(request):
    if request.user.is_authenticated:
         customer=request.user.customer
         order=Order.objects.get_or_create(customer__user=customer,complete=True)
         items=order.orderitem_set.all()
         print(items)
    else:
        items=[]

    context={"items":items}
    return render(request,'store/Cart.html',context)
```

Comment: i get this error when i add your suggestion Cannot query "nabil": Must be "User" instance.